# Set printer Excel vba macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Im trying to print through a macro to a shared printer on a colleagues PC.

I have tried the following but to no avail

```
Sub Tag()
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 1).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 1).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")

'Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1:A2").Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").WrapText = True
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Font.Size = 44
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").ShrinkToFit = True

Application.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer on XPSPort"

'Worksheets("Sheet1").PrintOut ActivePrinter = "DYMO LabelWriter 450 (Copy2) on JCSP55J"


End Sub
```

the JCSP55J is the colleagues network name.

any ideas how to solve this please?

Comment: Try to record a macro. It'll show the correct name and syntax.

Comment: I have tried to record the macro but it does not show activeprinter,

Answer (score 1):

You can add the ActivePrinter as an argument to PrintOut.

For example:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").PrintOut ActivePrinter:="DYMO LabelWriter 450 (Copy2) on JCSP55J"
```

Comment: HI, this still gives the same error, Run-Time error '1004': Method 'ActivePrinter' of object'_Global' failed

Comment: @Ryanagray That occurs if you're using the wrong name. Make sure you're using the name from the first box in "Printing Preferences" *exactly* as it occurs. http://i.imgur.com/KhBkTdT.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried this and still the same, does it make a difference it been a shared printer on another PC usb port

Comment: @Ryanagray Shouldn't do, it's only using the name to interface. Perhaps rename the printer device to something simpler to be sure, just "DYMO" or something

Comment: I have tried with other printers and still the same, I have edited the question above to include all the macro code, any more thoughts please?

Comment: @Ryanagray Hm. Try without the " on XXXXX" bit. Thinking about it, that might just be the port name suffixed to it

Comment: Still no joy, even with my other network printer

Answer (score 0):

I came from the feature looking for this post and I found the solution

```
Worksheets("[Sheet Where you wanna print]").PrintOut ActivePrinter:="[printer network route]"
```

it works better if you put an IP address of the computer \ a short name of a printer